# DCT coefficients and MV extraction in ffmpeg Mpeg-4 encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-4, dct, libx264

I'm using ffmpeg and libx264 to encode a video and I want to extract the DCT coefficients and motion vector of each frame during the encoding process.

What is the best way to do this?

I read in the ffmpeg manual that is possible to use the debug mode with some flags to extract these values. I tried `ffmpeg -debug dct_coeff` to output the dct coefficients but this option doesn't work for me; is it deprecated or related to a specific ffmpeg version?

Another option would be to modify and recompile ffmpeg source code but I don't know in which part of the code DCT and MV are calculated.

Any help with the debug mode or code modification suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: the `dct_coeff` flag is for `mpegvideo`. For motion vectors you can see `doc/examples/extract_mvs.c`. You need to use `-flags2 +export_mvs` to save them as frame side-data.

Comment: thanks for your comment, so there is no way to extract the dct coefficients used in libx264 encoding ?

Comment: You might need to look directly in the `x264` lib source

Comment: I solved the problem Using a modified version of JMreference tool by VQEG [link](http://vqegstl.ugent.be/?q=ModJM) that allows to generate an xml trace file containing both Motion Vectors and Residual coefficients (DCT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VQEG team modified version of JMreference tool for H.264 ([link](http://vqegstl.ugent.be/?q=ModJM)) allows to generate an xml trace file decoding an .264 video. The trace file contains all the information about the bitstream including Motion Vectors and residuals of each pixel (Obtained from DCT transform).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options to try:

-->Using x264 source code is much better than ffmpeg because of complex code in ffmpeg. You can download x264 from [here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) and look at the encoder/me.c file. It has several block matching algorithms out of which one is selected based on the encoding settings. From there, after searching, you can get the MV_x and MV_y

-->Using ffmpeg code as suggested by aergistal or use ffplay/mplayer to display motion vectors while decoding as below:

```
ffplay -flags2 +export_mvs input.mp4
```

--> You can use this ready-made tool [here](https://github.com/vadimkantorov/mpegflow)

Comment: I'd wager that h264 encoding or decoding is best done on the GPU.